# CKEditor Image Upload show response in window

Tags: php, file-upload, ckeditor, image-uploading

From the page, CKEditor sends the file to PHP code.
PHP saves the file correctly and generates a JSON response.

```
{
  "uploaded": 1,
  "fileName": "266dbc33b1fb783ba3bad4285ecc11ab.png",
  "url": "http://localhost/CodeIgniter2/img/266dbc33b1fb783ba3bad4285ecc11ab.png"
}
```

Why doesn't CKEditor use this data in image form? CKEditor only shows the data instead of the form with file upload.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using CKEditor 4.5+ with the [Upload Image plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/uploadimage). Note that this plugin is not included in the standard nor full package.

Comment: it comes with this plugin. I used builder to create build with this plugin.

Comment: Now I see that you said that PHP saves image. It means that upload image plugin is there and works correctly, but it looks like it does not get or handle the response.

Comment: There are several places you can start debugging. Check if the response in received and parsed: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/09b0cca/plugins/filetools/plugin.js#L67-L97 if the update event is fired and handled: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/09b0cca/plugins/uploadwidget/plugin.js#L230-L270 and if the `onuploaded` method is called: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/09b0cca/plugins/uploadimage/plugin.js#L58-L63